# Select relevant features with PCA and K-MEANS

Tags: algorithm, k-means, pca

I am trying to understand **PCA** and **K-Means** algorithms in order to extract some **relevant** features from a set of features.

I don't know what branch of computer science study these topics, seems on internet there aren't good resources, just some paper that I don't understand well. An example of paper [http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/~qitian/e_paper/icip02/icip02.pdf](http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/%7Eqitian/e_paper/icip02/icip02.pdf)

I have csv files of pepole walks composed as follow:

- **TIME**, **X**, **Y**, **Z**, these values are registred by the accelerometer

What I did

- I transformed the dataset as a table in Python
- I used  **tsfresh**, a Python library, to extract from each walk a vector of features, these features are a lot, **2k+ features** from each walk.
- I have to use **PFA**, Principal Feature Analysis, to select the **relevant** features from the set of
  vectors features

In order to do the last point, I have to reduce the dimension of the set of features walks with **PCA** (**PCA** will make the data different from the original one cause it modifies the data with the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the covariance matrix of the original data). Here I have the first question:

- How the input of PCA should look? The rows are the number of walks and the columns are the features or viceversa, so the rows are the number of the features and the columns are the number of walks of pepole?

After I reduced this data, I should use the **K-Means** algorithm on the reduced 'features' data. How the input should look in the K-Means? And what's the propouse on using this algorithm? All I know this algorithm it's used to 'cluster' some data, so in each cluster there are some 'points' based on some rule. What I did and think is:

- If I use in PCA an input that looks like: the rows are the number of walks and the columns are the number of features, then for K-Means I should change the columns with rows cause in this way each point it's a feature (but this is not the original data with the features, it's just the reduced one, so I don't know). So then for each cluster I see with euclidean distance who has the lower distance from the centroid and select that feature. So how many clusters I should declare? If I declare that the clusters are the same as the number of features, I will extract always the same number of features. How can I say that a point in the reduced data correspond to this feature in the original set of features?

I know it's not correct what I am saying maybe, but I am trying to understand it, can some of you help me? If am I in the right way? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the **PCA**, make sure you separate the understanding of the method the algorithm uses (eigenvectors and such) and the result. The result, is a linear mapping, mapping the original space `A`, to `A'`, where possibly, the dimension (number of features in your case) is less than the original space `A`.

So the first feature/element in space `A'`, is a linear combination of features of `A`.

The row/column depends on implementation, but if you use [scikit PCA](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/datasets/plot_iris_dataset.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-datasets-plot-iris-dataset-py) the columns are the features.

You can feed the **PCA** output, the `A'` space, to **K-means**, and it will cluster them, based on a space of usually reduced dimension.

Each point will be part of a cluster, and the idea is that if you would calculate K-Means on `A`, you would probably end up with the same/similar clusters like with `A'`. Computationally `A'` is a lot cheaper. You now have a clustering, on `A'` and `A`. As we agree that points similar in `A'` are also similar in `A`.

The number of clusters is difficult to answer, if you don't know anything search the elbow method. But say you want to get a sense of different type of `things` you have, I argue go for 3~8 and not too much, compare 2-3 points closest to
each center, and you have something consumable. The number of features can be larger than the number of clusters. e.g. If we want to know the most dense area in some area (2D) you can easily have 50 clusters, to get a sense where 50 cities could be. Here we have number of cluster way higher than space dimension, and it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do I know which feature is more relevant than another? I mean if you modify the original data, the index of the first feature in the original data is the same as the first index feature in the modified data? My code looks like that https://dpaste.com/5THH44R2N, the PFA method on the data is used in line 72. Should I do also the line 26? I mean as I told you, the data in the rows there are the walks and in the columns there are the features, so in this way I change the rows with the columns, so a row(that is a point) is a feature.

Comment: Also my Elbow method, looks like this, it not seems an elbow lol https://imgur.com/a/d7o5XCY

Comment: Say we have 5 features in the original data, a, b, c, d,e. Than in the PCA transformed data, reduced to 3 features x, y, z, feature x is a linear combination, so x = 2 * a + 4 * b - 0.5* d.

Comment: It is difficult to think of a way to tell feature relevancy in this. When there is no target/goal. PCA is sensitive for scaling, so be careful with what conclusions you draw.

Comment: I have a matrix of X vectors that represent the number of walks, each vector has Y features which are the elements of the vector. So the reduction is not about to reduce the X number of walks I have, but to reduce the Y features in it? Cause if I print the 'trasformed' data I have the same number of features but the number of walks  (so each vector) become the number of components that I choose

Comment: In that case you did not apply PCA well, and need to transpose the data first.

Comment: So now from (2289 features, 108 walks),after PCA I have (20 features, 108 walks), so as you said the features are a linear combination of other features. To declare 20 components I used the data you said (2289 features (rows), 108 walks (columns)) and from this data I calculate the Explained variation of the data, so the graphic looks like that (a bit strange) https://imgur.com/a/kR6tjiH, is 20 a good declaration of the components?